# Getting Login to Work Correctly

Tags: php, authentication

**HTML:**

Html of the two forms, looks like:
[image: img1]

when either buyer or merchant is selected..
[image: img2]

```
        <form action="#" method="post"> 
                Buyer <input type="radio" name="addType" value="Buyer" /> 
                &nbsp;&nbsp;Merchant <input type="radio" name="addType" value="Merchant" /><br />
                New PricedWrite User? <a href="../register">Register</a>
        </form>
        <div class="buyer">
            <form method="post" action="check_buyer.php">
                Username or Email: <input class="UserReg" style="width:350px;" type="text" name="userName" /> <br />
                Password:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <input class="UserReg" style="width:350px;" type="password"  name="userPass" /> <br />
                <input type="submit" class="UserReg" name="submit" value="Sign In" />
            </form>
        </div><!--/buyer-->
        <br />
        <div class="merch">
            <form method="post" action="check_merchant.php">
                Username or Email: <input class="UserReg" style="width:350px;" type="text" name="userName" /> <br />
                Password: <input class="UserReg" style="width:350px;" type="password" name="userPass" /> <br />
                <input type="submit" class="UserReg" name="submit" value="Sign In" />
            </form>
```

**check_buyer.php (which is in same directory as html file)**

```
<?php
require_once('../inc/db/dbc.php');
$connect = mysql_connect($h, $u, $p) or die ("Can't Connect to Database.");
mysql_select_db($db);

$LoginUserName = $_POST['userName'];
$LoginPassword = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['userPass']);
//connect to the database here
$LoginUserName = mysql_real_escape_string($LoginUserName);
$query = "SELECT uUPass, dynamSalt
        FROM User
        WHERE uUName = '$LoginUserName';";
$result = mysql_query($query);
if(mysql_num_rows($result) < 1) //no such user exists
{
    echo "No Such User";
}
$ifUserExists = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC);

$dynamSalt = $ifUserExists['dynamSalt'];  #get value of dynamSalt in query above
$SaltyPass = hash('sha512',$dynamSalt.$LoginPassword);


if($SaltyPass != $ifUserExists['uUPass']) //incorrect password
{
    echo "No Such Pass<br />";
    echo '$LoginPass Value: '.$LoginPassword;
}

else
{
echo "Success";
}

?>
```

Currently, when I type in a valid user and pass, it basically just reloads the page. What is wrong with this?

The way I originally create the pass upon registration is:

```
if(!empty($_POST['userPass']))
    $escapedInputtedPass=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['userPass']);
    $dynamSalt = mt_rand(); 
    $SaltyPass = hash('sha512',$dynamSalt.$escapedInputtedPass);
```

Why isn't this matching the way I check it? The only difference is, it doesnt have to generate the pass, because the pass in now stored under the `dynamSalt` column in the `user table`. Anyone see anything??
        $SaltyPass = hash('sha512',$dynamSalt.$escapedInputtedPass);

Comment: Instead of redirecting (with the `header('Location: index.php')` line), return error messages (specific error messages), this way you'll know what if statement is failing, and therefore what is going wrong. If none of your error messages are returned, then it isn't even trying to validate the login information, meaning you have the form setup incorrectly.

Comment: If I do this, I get error messages like this: `No Such PassSuccess at last!`

Comment: What is redirecting? The invalid user or pass?

Comment: Its saying the pass entered is wrong, however, see the code i added at the end (above) of how I generate the pass in the first place.

Comment: I see one difference. When you store the password, you first use this function mysql_real_escape_string . When you chech, you give the clean string, infact you use this $LoginPassword = $_POST['userPass']; and, of course, this make a difference.

Comment: And just to triple check, you hashed the hash in the db with the same hash, same algorithm (sha512) etc?  Print out both hashes and see what they are.

Comment: So should `$LoginPassword = $_POST['userPass']` be `$LoginPassword = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['userPass'])` as well ?

Comment: Yes, you must use mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['userPass']) before the test.

Comment: Please see updated `php code`, it appears not to affect the outcome, I'm still getting `No Such Pass`

Comment: I tried echoing out the value of `$LoginPass`, and it gave me: `$LoginPass Value: pass`

Comment: Figured it out. Stupid Mistake on my part! Lol, multiple "joe" in the database. Thanks for all your help guys!!!

Comment: @meow This is really bad. Username should be Primary Key or, at least, Unique.

Comment: username has a uID with it. I just haven't added in any validation yet since this is 'just the beginning' of the system.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I tink you have error in query:

```
$query = "SELECT uUPass, dynamSalt
        FROM User
        WHERE uUName = '$LoginUserName';";

//change to

$query = "SELECT uUPass, dynamSalt
        FROM User
        WHERE uUName = '$LoginUserName'"; //semicolon removed
```

Hope that works

Comment: Why this should make a difference?

Comment: See the way i figured it out.

Comment: @AurelioDeRosa: Do you think, using semicolon that way in a sql  query is good.....even if it makes no difference!

Comment: @Sudhir Using (or not) the semicolon in that way makes no difference but you post your message as a solution to the problem. Obviously it isn't because it really makes no difference and so your post is a non-sense.